# I have multiple controllers in web api MVC but Help page is showing only one controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my project i have multiple controllers but when compile it. It shows only some method of one controller. I am stuck in this problem from two days. Can any one help me out. I will be very thankful to you.
It is global.asax file.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }
```

Here is Web config:

```
public class WebConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
         //   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "apsi-info",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
```

This is one of the controller class:

```
namespace EpubAPI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Announce")]

    public class AnnouncementController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        [Route("GetData")]
        [HttpGet]
        public List<EAnnouncement> Get(string code)
        {
            return AnnouncementC.getdata(code);
        }

        [Route]
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(EAnnouncement announcement)
        {
            AnnouncementC.insert(announcement);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Code is attached above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify it is pubilc, it ends with controller and you have routing

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "API Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

In WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Still have the same problem.

Comment: Are those controller accessible from  client ?